# Rails restful namespaces, resources... newbie question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-routes

I'm attempting to use nested controllers that have restful pathing, so that I'm all organized and such.  Here's a copy of my routes.rb so far:

```
 map.root :controller => "dashboard"

  map.namespace :tracking do |tracking|
    tracking.resources :companies
  end

  map.namespace :status do |status|
    status.resources :reports
  end
```

Links to children controller paths work fine right now,

```
<%= link_to "New Report", new_status_report_path, :title => "Add New Report" %>
```

But my problem ensued when I tried to map to just the parent controller's index path.

```
<%= link_to "Status Home", status_path, :title => "Status Home" %>
```

I end up getting this when I load the page with the link:

```
undefined local variable or method `status_path'
```

Are my routes set correctly for this kind of link?

UPDATE: I should add that no data is associated with the parent "status" controller.  It merely acts as the category placeholder for the rest of the controllers associated with statuses, eg: reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you want /status to go to the status controller it should be a resource, not a namespace. You nest resources in much the same way:

```
map.resource :status do |status|
  status.resources :reports
end
```

Comment: perhaps I'm confused on what a namespace is, but my "status" category doesn't have any data directly associated with it.  It's just a placeholder category for organization's sake.  What I'm trying to do is just have it render a landing page for that category with links to things like reports etc.

Comment: A resource doesn't have to have data associated with it. If you want there to be a page at "/status", you have to route it somewhere. If you want to keep your routes restful, you should make a StatusesController and make status a singular resource as above. Then /status will go to the show method of StatusesController. On the other hand, sometimes apps will have a PagesController for all the pages that don't fit well as resource routes, you can route it like `map.status "/status", :controller => :pages, :action => :status`

Answer (score 0):

A namespace isn't a resource.

```
map.resources :statuses do |status|
  status.resources :reports
end
```

Also, your call to status_path needs an ID.

`status_path(:id => @status.id)`

or

`status_path(@status)`

Comment: well my status isn't a resource, the reports are.  there isn't such thing in my project as a status id.

Comment: Then please update your post so that the question mentions what it is you're trying to accomplish with "status_path".